# The algorithm of generating password is defective，how to improve it？

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

Is there any algorithm that can help me control the complexity of my password?
I use nextInt of java random to select characters for splicing, from a string composed of all kinds of characters. But the effect is not very good.
When generating an 8-bit password, there are too many alphabetic characters and less numeric characters due to random algorithm; Sometimes special symbol characters are missing; etc.

I hope to generate a password without repeated characters. When the generated password contains repeated characters, I discard the password and cycle until a password that meets the standards appears. I expect to find a smarter way.

Generated password:
66ijf7Gd

Vi3BOXVp

PnS~sMDs

ENmOhCR9

Ls$oB9N7

password.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Password  {
    private static final String passwordString = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM~!@#$%^&*?";
    public Password(){
    }
    public String generateString(String passwordchain, int passwordlength, int range) {
        String passwordstr= "";
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < passwordlength; i++) {
            int a = random.nextInt(range);
            passwordstr = passwordstr + passwordchain.substring(a, a+1);
        }
        return passwordstr;
    }

    public String generate(int number, int lowercase, int uppercase, int specialsymbol, int length) {
        if (number > 0) {
            if (number > 0 && lowercase > 0 && uppercase > 0&&specialsymbol>0)//閫変腑4绉嶇被鍨嬪瘑鐮?
            {
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(0, 72), length, 72);
            }

            if (number > 0 && lowercase > 0)//閫変腑鏁板瓧鍜屽皬鍐欏瓧姣嶇殑瀵嗙爜
            {
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(0, 36), length, 36);
            }
            if (number > 0 && uppercase > 0)//閫変腑鏁板瓧鍜屽ぇ鍐欏瓧姣嶇殑瀵嗙爜
            {
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(0, 10) + passwordString.substring(36, 62), length, 36);
            }
            if (number > 0 && specialsymbol > 0)//閫変腑鏁板瓧鍜岀壒娈婄鍙风殑瀵嗙爜
            {
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(0, 10) + passwordString.substring(62, 72), length, 21);
            }
            //鍙?変腑鏁板瓧鐨勫瘑鐮?
            return generateString(passwordString.substring(0, 10), length, 10);
        }
        if (lowercase > 0) {
            if(lowercase > 0 && uppercase > 0&&specialsymbol > 0){//閫変腑灏忓啓瀛楁瘝鍜屽ぇ鍐欏瓧姣嶅拰鐗规畩绗﹀彿鐨勫瘑鐮?
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(10, 72), length, 62);
            }
            if (lowercase > 0 && uppercase > 0) {//閫変腑灏忓啓瀛楁瘝鍜屽ぇ鍐欏瓧姣嶇殑瀵嗙爜
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(10, 62), length, 52);
            }
            if (lowercase > 0 &&specialsymbol > 0) {//閫変腑灏忓啓瀛楁瘝鍜岀壒娈婄鍙风殑瀵嗙爜
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(10, 36)+passwordString.substring(62,72),length,36);
            }
            //鍙?変腑灏忓啓瀛楁瘝鐨勫瘑鐮?
            return generateString(passwordString.substring(10, 36), length, 25);
        }
        if (uppercase > 0) {
            if(uppercase > 0&&specialsymbol > 0){//鍙惈鏈夊ぇ鍐欏瓧姣嶅拰鐗规畩绗﹀彿鐨勫瘑鐮?
                return generateString(passwordString.substring(36, 72), length, 36);
            }
            //鍙惈鏈夊ぇ鍐欏瓧姣嶇殑瀵嗙爜
            return generateString(passwordString.substring(36, 62), length, 26);
        }
        if(specialsymbol>0){//鍙惈鏈夌壒娈婄鍙风殑瀵嗙爜
            return generateString(passwordString.substring(62, 72), length, 10);
        }
        return " ";
    }
}
```

UniquePassword.java

```
package passwordgenerator;

public class UniquePassword extends Password implements Unique{
    private String str;

    public UniquePassword() {
        super();
        str=super.generate(1,0,0,0,8);
    }
    public static boolean containRepeatChar(String str){
        if(str==null||str.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        char[] elements=str.toCharArray();
        for(char e:elements){
            if(str.indexOf(e)!=str.lastIndexOf(e)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public String uniquegenerate(int number, int lowercase, int uppercase, int specialsymbol, int length) {
        while(containRepeatChar(str)){
            str=super.generate(number,lowercase,uppercase,specialsymbol,length);
            if(!containRepeatChar(str)){
                break;
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: "less numeric characters due to random algorithm". How many numeric characters do you want?

Comment: The quantity is entered by the user himself. When I test my code, I found that the amount of each character is not balanced in 8-bit passwords, such as ENmOhCR9, including 5 uppercase letters ，2 lowercase letters, 1 number, no special symbols.

Comment: 'When I generate a password without repeated characters, I discard the repeated characters': this is a self-contradiction. Please clarify.

Comment: I corrected the description. It's "I discard the password containing repeated characters".

Comment: `I hope to generate a password without repeated characters.` that is actually a bad idea. One of the design flaws of the German Enigma machine in WW2 was: it never encrypted a char with itself. That REDUCED the range of possible encryptions, and in turn that helped defeating it. So: true randomness OF COURSE allows for the same char to show up more than once. Your restriction thus makes your passwords LESS secure. The only thing you should really worry about: the different ranges of chars you want to use, and the probability you want each of those to have.

Comment: If an 8-bit password has repeated characters, I think, it's too simple and insecure. Of course, while a password contains 64 bits even long, it naturally requires repeated characters.

Comment: An 8 **char** password is mostly regarded "not secure" enough anyway. When doing brute force really doesn't care whether there is a repeated char or not. You only make your algorithm more complex, and thus easier to get wrong. And again: you make your end result **less random**. That means that (at least theoretically) an attacker could exploit this deficiency in your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a requirement for certain categories of characters to appear a certain number of times in your password (keeping in mind that this will make your password *less* random), then there is a good approach:

1. make a `List<Character>` and put the required number of characters from each category in the `List`. (picked at random from each category)
2. Call `Collections.shuffle` with that `List`
3. Concatenate the characters from the `List` that are now randomly shuffled, into a String (using a `StringBuilder`)

For `Collections.shuffle`, but also for picking random characters from each category, you need a `SecureRandom` instance, not an ordinary `Random`, as an ordinary `Random` is too predictable. (that's a very short summary of the problem)

---

If you merely want a higher chance of having numbers special characters without a guarantee that they'll appear in your password, then you can take your code and repeat/duplicate the portions of `passwordString` that you want to give a higher chance of appearing in your passwords.

Your existing code also needs to use a `SecureRandom`, though.